# Cell shows #NAME? after VBA inputs formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

```
Cells(intRow, 2 + j).Formula = "=SUM(C" & intRow & ":" & colName & intRow & ")"
```

This is the code I am using to put a basic SUM-functionality into the cells at the end of certain rows. Upon entering this formula in the cell, the cell shows "#NAME?". If i click into the formula and then press "Enter", the formula works as intended (the formula input is also correct).

Is there a way to make VBA update these cells automatically, so the formula works as soon as it's entered into the cell by VBA?

Edit: Example values for the variables are:

```
intRow = 5
j = 7 (Column G)
colName = H (refers to j + 1)
```

So the finished formula in cell K5 would be:

```
=SUM(C5:J5)
```

Comment: What does `"=SUM(C" & intRow & ":" & colName & intRow & ")"` evaluate to? You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Do you have calculation on automatic? Is the cell format correct initially (i.e. General)

Comment: So, we are not going to be able to answer this without knowing the values of the variables at the time of the error.  You need to show more of your code.  We need to see how the variables are declared and what value is being assigned to them.

Comment: In general, `#NAME?` error occurs when you misspell the formula i.e. an invalid formula. Though the cell show `#NAME?`, did you look at the `formula bar`? What does the formula bar show? That would give you an idea about what formula is being placed in the cell.

Comment: For clarification: The error is thrown in the cell (not when executing the code), until I click inside the formula bar (which displays the correct formula) and press "Enter". After that it works as intended.

Comment: 7 = G not I.

9 = H

The code works apart from that. Is your calculation on automatic.

Comment: Fixed the columns, my bad.
I don't think it is on automatic(I wouldn't know how to change it), but I tried calculating the sheet after the putting in the formulas with:
Sheets(i).Calculate
This didn't solve the problem, cells still showed #NAME? until i manually updated every single one.

Comment: I've had something similar with Excel 2016 64bit - UDF's wouldn't calculate despite being set to volatile, automatic calculation, F9 and selection.calculate. The only solution I found was to search for "=" and replace it with "=" this actually made it recalculate. I suspect there's a bug in Excel's routine for spotting what needs recalculating

Comment: @HarassedDad This works, thank you. This still only works if I do it manually, not if I run this exact Search and Replace inside my code, did you do it manually as well?

Comment: yep. It happens completely randomly so I just do it manually when it happens - but I can get it to work from a macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Using

```
.FormulaR1C1
```

does not cause the same error.

> Cells(intRow, 2 + j).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[" & -(j - 1) & "]:RC[" &
>   (-1) & "])"

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, for a different reason, but I think it may help someone else :

> It was due to a problem of localization (language)

I'm a French user and I was trying the following code :

`For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
   cel.FormulaR1C1 = "=SI(R[0]C[-1]=1,1,0)"
Next cel`

Where `SI` corresponds to the formula `IF` in English.

The problem is that `FormulaR1C1` accept only English Formula: so to fix it I had to use :

`For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
   cel.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[0]C[-1]=1,1,0)"
Next cel`

---

Otherwise I can also use my French formula thanks to `FormulaR1C1Local` such as :

`For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
  cel.FormulaR1C1Local = "=SI(L(0)C(1)=1;1;0)"
Next cel`

(note that `L`/`C` are for french words : `Ligne/Colonne`, that I needed to use the separator `;` , that brackets are replaced by parenthesis in the Excel's French world ..)